# Split ONE input field into SEVERAL HTML

Tags: html, field

How can I split ONE input field in several pieces maintaining the input string non-splited? Thus the string is "splitted" only visually. 

So if user will input "12345678", obviously the submitting result will be: field="12345678", submitting "12345678" to server. 
So how can I make:
field1="12"
field2="34"
field3="56"
field4="78"
STILL submitting "12345678" to server?

P.S.Sorry, explained as simple as I could=)

Comment: How are you submitting this to the server? javascript or?

Comment: Add a hidden input field to contain the unsplit value. Use JavaScript to copy the values from the split fields into the main field.

Comment: Submitting using js.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to add  each of the fields together (careful not to add the actual numbers), then make a field in which the user cannot edit, and assign your new value to this, then send this to the server, hope I explained that okay!

Comment: That's actually a nice idea. Let me try.

Comment: @MastersWRC Let me know how you get on

Comment: I'm almost there! Still have an issue. Js conjucts two strings together and inserts the result in the hidden field. How can I submit data to server from the HIDDEN field? 
` <script type="text/javascript">
function join()
</script>   
<form action="/search.php" method="POST"  onsubmit="return checkSearch();">
<input id="result" type="hidden"  value="" style="solid #494846;">
</form>
<form>
<input id="a" type="text" oninput="join();" >
<input id="b" type="text" oninput="join();" >
</form>`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function join()
{
var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
document.getElementById('result').value = a+b;
}
</script>

Comment: @MastersWRC Have you solved it yet? You should be able to submit it just as you would a regular field.

Comment: Yeah, I did! I'll give you the url to check it out when I finish.

Answer (score -1):

**SOLUTION:**
Basically all you need is this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function join()
{
var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
document.getElementById('result').value = a+b;
}
</script>
```

You have to make 3 independent fields: **1 hidden** and two regular ones. Hidden field will be the result container. Script just add 2 values from regular fields and puts the result in HIDDEN one. So the HTML5 code is:

```
 <form action="/exec/search.php" method="POST"  onsubmit="return checkSearch();">
<input id="result" type="hidden" name="search" value="" style="border: 1px solid #494846; margin-left:25px;">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<form>
<input id="a" class="tiny" type="text" oninput="join();" onpaste="join();">
<input id="b" class="tiny" type="text" oninput="join();" onpaste="join();">

</form>
```

Thanks to Toby Cannon for help!

P.S. this is absolutely basic model. You can advance it however you wish.